# Trouble installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, nvidia, uefi

I'm having trouble installing Ubuntu on my laptop... I've tried a number of solutions I found on this and other forums but nothing worked.

What I'm trying to do is to install Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS on a Acer Aspire 7 A715-71G-743K with a 256 GB SSD and a 1 TB HDD, and a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050Ti graphics card which I suspect was the source of all my problems.

I did manage to install Ubuntu 16.04 a few months ago without any problem. When I found out that Ubuntu did not recognize any external monitor connected to the HDMI port I tried to update Nvidia drivers and some other solutions, but that only messed up the installation, as Ubuntu began freezing at login. Thus I tried to install Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04 (just before feature freeze release), both of which worked for a while, but then Ubuntu stopped booting.

Thus I backed-up my data and reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS from live USB. I want to put the OS on the SSD and data on the HDD. Since the boot uses UEFI, I partitioned the SSD into a 64 MB EFI partition and a Ext4 partition with mount point / and put the /home mount point on a Ext4 partition on the HDD after reserving a ~4 GB partition as swap.

The installation went fine, but when I attempted to reboot the system from the live session, it froze, and I had to shut it down using the power button. When rebooted, it reaches as far as the login screen, where I am able to login with my username and password, but then it freezes... I can move the cursor using the touch pad but that's it. At that point I cannot access virtual consoles (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>), although that works before logging in...

(**edit** - as happened in the live session, Ubuntu freezes when I try to reboot or simply shut it down)

I see this appears to be a common issue, but no other solution I found online helped. What troubles me most is that both Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10 did work before, I do not understand what changed...

I'm thinking of trying other Linux distributions but at this point I'm afraid I'll just end up having some similar problem...

Any help is really appreciated.

**EDIT**
I managed to configure a connection to a wifi network and to install the latest nvidia driver (nvidia-390). This fixed the problem with freezing at reboot/shut down. It also prevents the system from freezing at login, but does not solves the problem: as I enter my password and login, I see Ubuntu's background and after a few seconds I am bounced back to the login screen... I really don't know if this is hilarious or frustrating...!

**EDIT**
So, it turns out that what I'm experiencing is the infamous Ubuntu Login Loop, which I did not know. Fascinating.
I tried a number of solutions I found online (all from `tty1`), including:

- install nvidia drivers other than `nvidia-390`
- changing owner of .Xauthority (and .ICEauthority) files, and/or moving them into a .bak
- running `dpkg-reconfigure` on lightdm or reinstall it

none of which worked.

I installed `lxdm`, and now I am able to login successfully with the LXDE desktop environment. Not really what I wanted, but it's something.

I checked `.xsession-errors` after an attempt to log in, it says:

```
Xlib:  extention "GLX" missing on display ":0"
Xlib:  extention "GLX" missing on display ":0"
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2609) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (2597) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: logrotate main process (2444) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_sbin_upstart.108.crash) main process (2491) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_unity_compiz-config-profile-setter.999.crash) main process (2496) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity-paenl-service main process (2623) killed by TERM signal
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (2512) killed by TERM signal
upstart: job indicator-bluetooth failed to stop
```

**EDIT**
Apparently, all I had to do was uninstall all nvidia drivers... Now I can log in normally. I wonder what ugly side effects this will have...

**EDIT**
So, in the end I think I'll stick to running without nvidia drivers til Ubuntu 18.04 is released in mid April, that should fix most problems (indeed, when I tried it, it immediately recognized external HDMI monitors, the very first problem that caused me to go through this frustrating ordeal...)
For other users with the same problem (Ubuntu 16.04 and Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050Ti) [this link may help](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2353796).
Also, CatChMeIfUCan's suggestion of looking on the web for the correct driver version for my setup seems the most reasonable thing to do, though I could not find anything very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Does lxdm not let you choose your DE? If you want Unity or Gnome, `sudo apt install gdm` worked for me and fixed the login loop while still letting me use Unity. You'll have to do it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F6</kbd> and then do `sudo service lightdm stop` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` as [CatChMeIfUCan](https://askubuntu.com/a/1011894/782803) said. Lightdm doesn't play nicely with Nvidia GPUs, although gdm works for me. If Unity got uninstalled somehow you can get it back with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. Then `$ reboot` after you've done everything. This works fine with Nvidia 384 and 390 drivers for me (using GTX 1060). But if nouveau works fine with your GPU and lightdm, then don't do anything. Ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: Yes, lxdm lets me choose the DE, but only LXDE worked (and this actually doesn't sound as a solution to me). For some reason, when I switch to gdm (and reboot) I cannot connect to my wifi network... thus I'm gonna rule that out as a solution (for my case) as it would require some additional troubleshooting. As for nouveau, it probably worked at the very beginning, I may have broken it somehow trying to solve the nvidia drivers problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this on tty1

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

then

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

sudo service lightdm restart
```

if did not work try this

```
sudo apt-get install gdm


sudo service lightdm stop


sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

select gdm instead of lightdm

then

```
 sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just edited my question, removing nvidia drivers did the work. I'm trying your solution just now, seems you know better than my blind attempts.

Comment: np but Ubuntu and most Linux distro's have problem with Nvidia GPU's you must install the correct specific version take a look at your graphic card details with this command `sudo  lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs -i lspci -v -s {}`  and search on the web for correct version with your ubuntu version and also watch for other peoples result's too but keep trying to test versions you will find the correct one